# Only allowing certain websites access PHP API

Tags: javascript, php, api, security, rest

I am currently facing the problem of securing up an API my clients use on their websites. However because this API is called by JavaScript I'm finding it hard to figure out a way to only allow these access the API/URL's.

So how would I go about this? How would I only allow access to these links. Obviously the links could be compromised but I would like to have a way to deny the script from operating if it hasn't come from an verified site. ATM all I can think of using is the Referrer header which as we all know, can be faked. Is there a way I can trace the source of the request? If so, how? Because then I could just check the source of the request and if it isn't an allowed source then just issue a 403 Forbidden.

Thanks. If you need any more information please feel free to ask!

Comment: why would someone fake a Referrer header to talk to your api? if you want it secret, make your customer hit the api in php and relay the response back to the client, possibly with auth, but definitely with SOP and related protections. you can also pass temp tokens from php to js, providing tokens only to certain php IP#s, and requiring tokens to query the API from js.

Comment: It's for a Shopify App which communicates via the shopify storefront with the app. So people could potentially use what the API offers on their website. And that also answers yours second question about why they could't just call it from PHP as you can't use custom PHP pages on shopify. You have to use javascript.

Comment: well the bottom line is that you have to either let the world use your API, or make your customers conceal it from the world entirely behind server scripting, limiting a breach to a certain customer ID.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would build a database table which listed the urls that you want to allow and also a unique key for each of them something like

> url = http://stackoverflow.com
>
> key = 9fc4c60c2f6b9aaba3a640e5e4b9bc4d

Then use basic auth to authenticate your calls and check the auth headers to match both the url and the key of every access.

This obviously depends on how you have built your API but as a tip [Slim PHP Framework](http://www.slimframework.com) is a great tool and has a really nice basic auth middleware

The other way is to have a php file which holds an array of all of your allowed sites and then check through this array for each call.

Comment: Hi, thankyou for your response. But if this key is visible as I mention the API get's called by JavaScript using Ajax, how would this stop people replicating the request? Thanks.

Comment: Well there is the kicker you may want to look at OAuth, however this is a large amount of work. If you really need to be secure then this maybe the only way. The problem with Javascript is that it is by it's nature open. Sorry to be there bearer of disappointing news

Comment: I will look into OAuth thanks. I love and hate javascript at the same time :( If only shopify allowed you to use custom PHP pages on your shops :(

Comment: oauth will not help because OP doesn't want to auth users, he wants to auth middleman sites by looking at users, which is not reliable. @user3228693: look into how google analytics verifies site ownership/embedded usage: that's very close to what you need to do.

Comment: Fair comment, which is why I suggested the answer I gave.

Comment: @dandavis isn't all google doing with their auth system(uploading a file to the host of the domain name) just proving that you have access to uploading to the website/own the website?

Comment: @user3228693: no, that's not all they are doing. they serve JS associated with a certain domain and handle requests made by that JS, in the name of a site, while screening out noise to the most reasonable level. it's as close a model as i can find in the real-world to what you're asking for.

Comment: Ok great thanks! I think I will try replicate what they do. That should get me as secure as possible and if anyone manages to get round that by replicating it then they can have access to the API, it isn't a THAT big deal.

Comment: if you don't need 100% security/accountability, and can still make a buck with mostly legit usage, just get it out there. later, you can always find ways to blacklist certain IPs, more aggressively validate headers, use hidden frames to write 3rd-domain cookies to your js server, etc... those measures should cut down waste, not make-or-break your operation, or else you need to refer to my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a whitelist on your server... I have no details on your server so I can't really elaborate much.

If you were using a node server you could have an array of trusted domains and send an error if the domain requesting your api isn't included. If you are reverse proxying to a node server or using some other language, you could also do something to a similar extent in apache/nginx/whatever you are using.

Comment: But if they was to access the URL via this site, using ajax, it would be the clients IP that would get picked up by the server if im correct?

Comment: The domain will always be a part of the http request, you need to see where the requests are coming from so that cross origin resource sharing rules can be enforced.