# How to communicate from AngularJS based frontend to REST API backend securely

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, security

I have created REST API with Spring Boot and Single Page Application powered by AngularJS.

The question is how to prevent everyone from using my REST api which is available publicly in the internet? I want it to be allowed for usage only from my webpage.

I can not use any secret/password/token from angular side as it would be visible to anyone.

Comment: I just want to help: [maybe this link gives you relevant information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24617452/only-allowing-certain-websites-access-php-api)

Answer (score 1):

Spring security can help with that. You can define some urls accessible by only certain users having certain roles.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    protected void configures(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/error").and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").hasAnyRole("USER_ROLE");
    }
}
```

So that, only those with role "USER_ROLE" can access any url starts with "/api".
In order to have this functionality, you have to implement a login system which assign the "USER_ROLE" to the users after successful login.

On AngularJs part, it is quite easy. You just make a http request to the REST api, since the browser holds cookies and JSESSIONID, it will be sent along with the request in the header. Spring picks it up and checks if the user having that JSESSIONID has authority to access the url.